# Measure of a set under diffeomorphism

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega,\Omega'\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded open sets. Let $F:\Omega\to\Omega'$ be a diffeomorphism.
Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact measurable set such that $A\subset\Omega$ and 
$$\lambda(A)\ge\alpha,$$ where $\lambda$ is the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure and $\alpha>0$.

Is it possible to prove that
$$\lambda(F(A))\ge C\alpha,$$ where $C>0$ depends just on $F$?

Comment: I understand that $\Omega$ and $A$ are fixed, whereas $F$ is any diffeomorphism from $\Omega$ onto some $\Omega'$.  $\Omega$ is the union of an increasing family of compact sets $K_n$,  so there is a compact $K \subset \Omega$ with $\lambda(\Omega \setminus K) \le \alpha/2$.  One must have $\lambda(A \cap K) \ge \alpha/2$. As $C$ we can take one half of the minimum of the absolute value of the Jacobian detetminant of $F$ on $K$.

Comment: Hello, I've just edited the question. Indeed the situation is different. It is $F$ to be fixed. Thanks for your answer @user539887

Comment: $\alpha$ constant?

Comment: yes @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla

Comment: Try proving this in one dimension.  Where the derivative if $F(x)$ goes to zero as $x$ goes to the boundary.  You should be able to get $\lambda(F(A))/\lambda(A)$ as close to zero as you like.

Comment: @GEdgar, $\Omega$ is bounded, so $x\to\infty$ in't possible.

Comment: Of course I meant $F'(x)$ goes to zero.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution supposing $\alpha$ constant.

Let be $C_n = \{x\in\Omega: |\det DF(x)| > 1/n\}$. $F$ diffeomorphism $\implies\Omega = \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty C_n$. Take $n_0$ s.t.  $\lambda(C_{n_0}) > \lambda(\Omega) - \alpha/2$.

If $\lambda(A)\ge\alpha$, $\lambda(C_{n_0}\cap A)\ge\alpha/2$.
Using the cov theorem:
$$
\lambda(F(A)) = \int_{F(A)}d\lambda =
\int_{A}|\det DF|\,d\lambda\ge
\int_{C_{n_0}\cap A}|\det DF|\,d\lambda\ge \alpha/2n_0
.$$

Answer (score 1):

Example: $n=1$, $\Omega = \Omega' = (0,1)$ and $F(x) = x^2$.  Then for $\alpha < 1/2$, let $A = [\alpha,2\alpha]$ to get $F(A) = [\alpha^2,4\alpha^2]$ so that $\lambda(A) = \alpha$ and $\lambda(F(A)) = 3\alpha^2$.  Note $\lambda(F(A))/\lambda(A) = 3\alpha$ can be as small as we like.

Comment: $\alpha$ is constant... See comments 4 and 5.

Comment: When he said $C$ depends just on $F$, I assumed $C$ does not depend on $\alpha$.

Comment: In any case, don't delete the answer. Is an interesting counterexample of "what happens with weaker hypothesis"?